# How To Place Buttons Around A Circle with HTML5 and CSS 3?

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas, css-shapes

I want to arrange 4 buttons (or bootstrap tabs,doesn't matter) around a circle and load a content in the middle of that circle,something like this:

[image]

How can i do that?

Comment: Hi, Can you please add some code snippets that you have tried, so others can help out or improve your code.

Comment: @sankoobaba
you are right,but i've no idea what can i do with canvas in html 5 and how to make curve buttons around it.

Comment: @AlirezaHafez you need to explore SVG files, and HTML5 Canvas tag. Hunt around search engines or here on StackOverflow and see what can come up to help you with these terms,

Comment: My 2-cents: If this is more than a 1-off task, then SVG is a great fit for your arcing tabs. You can define each arc in SVG. You can even shape the tab label text to follow the arc. Since SVG is a true DOM element, you automatically get hover & click capabilities. There is a learning curve with SVG, but once learned its a useful & flexible tool to display shapes other than the "boxy" divs. ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you could use a small bit of jquery to load your center circle with the text you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.quart').click(function() {
    var ind = $(this).index();
    switch (ind) {
      case 0:
        var tex = "div 1";
        break;
      case 1:
        var tex = "div 2";
        break;
      case 2:
        var tex = "div 3";
        break;
      case 3:
        var tex = "div 4";
        break;
    }
    $('.center').text(tex);
  });

});
```

```css
.wrap {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.quart {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background: tomato;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
.quart:first-child {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.quart:nth-child(2) {
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
}
.quart:nth-child(3) {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
}
.quart:nth-child(4) {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
.center {
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  background: lightgray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 160px;
}
.quart:hover {
  background: dimgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="quart"></div>
  <div class="quart"></div>
  <div class="quart"></div>
  <div class="quart"></div>
  <div class="center">Click My non-existent Corners!</div>
</div>
```

This probably won't be as efficient as an svg solution, but colud be altered to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HTML `<map>` tag - [more info](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)

Comment: mapping an image is a good idea, but i want to load dynamic contents in the buttons and in the middle of the circle too!

Comment: Map tags are bad for dynamic content and do not scale to the content, Maps are typically used on images and in this situation it would be better to approach the whole thing with SVG files rather than somewhat outdated (non-mobile friendly) `<map>` tags.